# Cant able to change the comment section, submit button text color style in IE7 in Drupal 7

Tags: css, forms, drupal-7

I am trying to add custom style for the comment form submit button

```
.form-actions .form-submit {
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    background-color: #CC0000;
    height: 40px;
}
```

It works in all the browser, but in IE7 its not working. Some overlay text color #A0A0A0 also coming.

### IE 7

[image]

### Other browser

[image]

note: all other submit button style are working fine, only in comment form submit button.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Inspect the element. It is possible that the submit button has another style that overrides this one.

Answer (score 0):

try `_color: #FFFFFF !important;`